# Converting String into Datetime in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I need to convert

```
DoB = pd.Series(["07Sep59","01Jan55","15Dec47","11Jul42"])
```

into a datetime object.

I am using below code :

```
DoB = pd.Series(["07Sep59","01Jan55","15Dec47","11Jul42"])
pd.to_datetime(DoB,format = '%d%b%y')
```

and it works perfectly fine with output as :

```
2059-09-07
2055-01-01
2047-12-15
2042-07-11
```

But I need `19XX` instead of `20XX`.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could insert '19' in the date after the month. Notice that you need to change the date format, and you need to work with `DoB.str` to enable string concatenation.

```py
DoB = pd.Series(["07Sep59","01Jan55","15Dec47","11Jul42"])
DoB = DoB.str[:-2]+'19'+DoB.str[-2:]
pd.to_datetime(DoB,format = '%d%b%Y')
```

output:

```
0   1959-09-07
1   1955-01-01
2   1947-12-15
3   1942-07-11
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```